# How to create angular nvd3 multibar and stacked chart using json data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I want to create an angular nvd3 multibar chart using the following json data.

```
json:
[
    {
        "ccpProducts": "CME",
        "color": "red",
        "values": [
            {
                "dates": "2015-07-01 00:00:00.0",
                "noOfTrades": 5281
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ccpProducts": "LCH",
        "color": "#6b486b",
        "values": [
            {
                "dates": "2015-07-01 00:00:00.0",
                "noOfTrades": 5281
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5VZnILzOI3HRLH1Tu7qh?p=preview. Pls see the plunker where i ma not able to see the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `values` is an array of objects, you can't access its attributes via their index like you are doing (object properties are not ordered):

```
// d[0] and d[1] are undefined!
x: function(d){ return new d[0]; },
y: function(d){ return d[1]; }
```

Instead you should do this:

```
x: function(d){ return new d['dates']; },
y: function(d){ return d['numOfTrades']; }
```

You could also transform the format of the data in `bar.json`.

Comment: I cannot chnage the structure of json. the second solution worked , but i am not able to see the legends. here is the plunker.http://plnkr.co/edit/5jmKwqeUJZC6oOIjUZU5?p=preview

Comment: For me the legends are displayed: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VGZgaZFGVtUFZtWU8V8r?p=preview)

Comment: I mean the legend lables are not working. I want to show CME,LCH from json in the legends.

Comment: I found out the solution I have to change the key of JSON from "CCPProducts" to "key"